# Projecting a set of 2d real numbers to constrained grid

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning

I have a set of 2D coordinates, ((x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn))
I want to transform them into a grid encoding their relative positions in a way that minimizes the information lost, e.g. :

```
[[(x4, y4), (x2, y2)]

 [(x3, y3), (x1, y1), (x5, y5)]]
```

With the constraint that there can only be up to five items on each "line" of the grid

Would encode the relationship:

(x4, y4) is to the left of (x2, y2): `x4 < x2`

(x4, y4) is above ((x3, y3), (x1, y1), (x5, y5)): `y4 > y3, y4 > y1, y4 > y5`

Any ideas? Or is this not a well-framed problem.

Comment: Wouldn't using the normal Cartesian system work?

Comment: A trivial solution is to sort them by $x$-coordinate and put them all in one row.